# How to decode '\u0040' to '@' by PHP

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I used Facebook API but Json returned:

```
{
   "id": "674271626114503",
   "email": "duc2521997\u0040gmail.com"
}
```

How to decode '\u0040' to '@' by PHP ?
Thanks.

Comment: Only take the easy option that is not the accepted answer and use `json_decode()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, here we are using `json_decode` will itself take care of `\u0040` to `@`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/794818)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string='{
   "id": "674271626114503",
   "email": "duc2521997\u0040gmail.com"
}';
$array=  json_decode($string,true); //this itself will take care of `\u0040`
echo $array["email"];
```

**Output:** `duc2521997@gmail.com`